# Issue with playing videos on chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am using chrome on ubuntu 18.04. Videos are not playing properly on chrome. Whether it is youtube or any other site the problem persists. When I am playing a video the video stops in between meaning the video won't move. However the audio remains ON and the time of the video also passes on. Just the video stops giving a standstill image. I would like to tell that I tried firefox and there is no problem with that. Also chrome works fine in windows 10. This problem is only in ubuntu. Please suggest what to do. When I touch the mousepad or just swap my fingers on it the video will again play but only for 2-3 seconds and again a standstill image.

I checked the version going in the help menu and it showing to be Version 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) (64-bit). Also it is not showing if I am on the latest version and neither it is not showing any option to update. I think it should be the latest version because I just installed chrome from the website and it must be updated.Is it a bug or something else

Comment: I have the same behaviour in chrome 72.0.3626.96 under the same Ubuntu version. One thing I noticed: When I move the mouse, the video continues. When the mouse is still, after some seconds, the video stops again. Do you have the same behaviour?

Comment: Yes. Not only moving the mouse but pressing any key works. But again after some seconds video stops and the sound keeps comming. You have any solution for this ?

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea how to fix this. But at least it seems to be the same error.